# How to change the order of function calls based on the value of a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin and I have the following situation:

```
$functions1 = 7;  //users can select this value and this can be something between 1-7  
$functions2 = 5;  //these values are positions to be precise 
$functions3 = 6;  //no two variables can have same value as each position is unique
$functions4 = 3;  //we can also make $functions1-7 an array to avoid making 7 variables
$functions5 = 4;
$functions6 = 2;
$functions7 = 1;
```

I need to change the order of executions these function calls based on the value of the relative variables mentioned above:

```
function1();
function2();
function3();
function4();
function5();
function6();
function7();
```

All these functions return some HTML like:

```
function1(){ return "<div>Hello World from function1</div>" }
.
.
function7(){return "<div>Hello World from function7</div>"}
```

In the current sequential form irrespective of the values of the $functions1-7 variables above, the functions will execute in the order in which they are called.

What is the best approach to change the order of the function calls based on the values of **$functions1-7** variables like if **$functions4 = 7** then function4() should be the last function call to be executed.

Please suggest an optimal approach to the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it 1 function that will return different results depending on the value of the variable:

```
function testFunction($var) {
    if ($var == 1)
        return "<div>Hello World from function1</div>";
    if ($var == 7)
        return "<div>Hello World from function7</div>";
    ...
}
```

then you can run it like this:

```
testFunction($functions1);
```

**EDIT**: First I didn't understand your question completely, so let me extend my answer.

In order to run the function in the required order, best is probably to use an array:

```
$array = array($functions1, $functions2, $functions3, $functions4, $functions5, $functions6, $functions7);
```

then do the same as above but put it in a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++)
    echo testFunction($array[$i]);
```

Here is a demo: http://3v4l.org/mgOKh

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using associative array and foreach for example

```
function Func3(){
    echo '3';
}
function Func1(){
    echo '1';
} 
$a = [3=>'Func3',1=>'Func1'];
ksort($a);
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $fname = $a[$k];
    $fname();
}
```

not tested.
resources:
[php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), [php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)